# How to push new VC by swiping left in last UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, swipe, uipageviewcontroller, pushviewcontroller

Is there any way to handle swipe left in last UIPageViewController?
Basically I have 3 intro screens and the last screen has a button to go to the app. I want to add the ability to do the same by swiping left.

my code:

```
func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc =    viewController as! AppChildIntroViewController
    var index =   vc.index
    if(index == 0){
        return nil
    }
    index -= 1
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}

func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
    let vc =    viewController as! AppChildIntroViewController
    var index =   vc.index
    index += 1
    if (index == 3) {
        return nil;
    }
    return self.viewControllerAtIndex(index)
}
```

I was trying to add a push action if **index == 3** but in this case it immediately goes to the app on the last screen

Comment: Can you not just put a swipe gesture recognizer on the view that checks for a left-swipe and calls the UIAction of the button?

Comment: I 've tried. It doesn't help because there is scrollview in pageview

Comment: Could you add a 4th page, and on viewWillAppear of the 4th page redirect to your starting view controller?

Comment: I can but I have to change number of pageviewcontrollers to 4 and in this case will be 4 dots at the bottom instead of 3